# Como manter a orientação da tela?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Gostaria de saber qual o código equivalente em Java para esse comando:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Justificativa: Estou criando um app com o Layout `NavigationDrawer`, e preciso que em determinadas telas (ou todas) mantenha as configurações quando o usuário girar o dispositivo.

Comment: Ja tentou colocar no manifest.xml? La tem como voce informar as orientacoes possiveis da activity, ai basta voce deixar uma fixa caso nao queira que mude a orientacao do dispositivo.

Comment: Já coloquei sim... Porque tipo, esse comando (até onde sei) deve ser colocado em cada activity, como só temos uma se tratando de NavigationDrawer, eu acabei colocando e não funcionou!

Comment: Que eu saiba isso não inibe a mudança de orientação. É isso que você quer? O título não condiz muito com a pergunta... Se for só a questão do `configChanges` programatico, não existe solução.

Comment: Você quer bloquear a rotação em sua tela? se for isto, eu posso lhe dizer como

Comment: @Wakim na verdade eu mudei o título de acordo com o que eu entendi do problema, cheguei a pesquisar o que fazia o código em questão mas não ficou 100% claro para mim. O título anterior era `Código equivalente em Java`, o que não quer dizer nada de absolutamente nada. Se você entendeu o problema e tiver um título melhor para sugerir pode editar a pergunta para corrigir, apenas tentei dar minha contribuição (que agora fiquei na dúvida se foi boa ou ruim, rs).

Comment: Olá, na verdade o título era exatamente com o quê eu queria, ou seja, queria uma outra forma de bloquear a tela por comando java em vez de xml no AndroidManifest.

Comment: E eu já conseguir, na verdade estava colocando no Manifest apenas o orientation em configChanges, e na verdade tenho que levar em consideração que o tamanho da tela também modificará. Dessa forma, segue a solução no próprio xml: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: @Math o código equivalente seria esse aqui:
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     Log.v("Passei", "1");
     if(isVisibleToUser) {
         Activity a = getActivity();
         if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
     }
 }

Comment: Você pode utilizar um comando Java também: `int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;        
if (currentOrientation == getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
 setRequestedOrientation(6);        
else 
 setRequestedOrientation(7);`

Comment: @TaironeDias dessa forma que você disse, você estará forçando a orientação sempre **PORTRAIT**, já a solução que te passei só bloqueia o giro, quer dizer que, o usuário pode usar em **LANDSCAPE** também porém não vai poder mudar uma vez que entrou na tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `setRequestedOrientation (int requestedOrientation)` no método `onCreate` da `Activity` que utiliza o `NavigationDrawer`.

Para [Informações sobre `setRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)) e para [Informações sobre o parâmetro](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation)